# Does postgresql require unique constraint names when defining FOREIGN KEYS

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

Here is my schema for database tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  device_id INTEGER,
  user_points INTEGER,
  cookie VARCHAR,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

 CREATE TABLE admins (
   admin_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   username VARCHAR,
   password VARCHAR
 );


 CREATE TABLE admin_adventure (
   adventure_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   admin_id INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (adventure_id)

 );

 CREATE TABLE adventures (
   adventure_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   prize_id INTEGER,
   novella_id INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (adventure_id)
 );
```

Here I'm trying to define FOREIGN KEYS:

```
ALTER TABLE  admin_adventure  ADD FOREIGN KEY ( admin_id ) REFERENCES  admins  ( admin_id );


ALTER TABLE  admin_adventure  ADD FOREIGN KEY ( adventure_id ) REFERENCES  adventures  ( adventure_id );
```

And here is the error I get when trying to migrate with Flyway:

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "admins"

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and why I get this error?

Comment: Yes, a unique or primary key is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is complaining that you are trying to link a foreign key to a column in another table which is not unique (e.g. a primary key).  Try making the `admin_id` column in the `admins` table a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
    admin_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR,
    password VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) says:

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.

So you must either

```
ALTER TABLE admins ADD PRIMARY KEY (admin_id);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE admins ADD UNIQUE (admin_id);
```